# Parsing twitter trending output as an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, twitter, hashtag

I'm trying to parse twitter trending data to isolate just trending hashtags (not topics), and either echo them or save them to a variable.  Currently I have the following code:

```
$json_output=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424977.json"),true);
print_r($json_output);
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [as_of] => 2012-01-19T18:13:39Z
        [trends] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [promoted_content] => 
                        [query] => %23youknowdamnwell
                        [name] => #youknowdamnwell
                        [events] => 
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/%23youknowdamnwell
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => %23WhyGuysNeedPrenups
                        [name] => #WhyGuysNeedPrenups
                        [promoted_content] => 
                        [events] => 
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/%23WhyGuysNeedPrenups
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => TWUG
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/TWUG
                        [promoted_content] => 
                        [name] => TWUG
                        [events] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => %22The%20Bark%20Side%22
                        [name] => The Bark Side
                        [promoted_content] => 
                        [events] => 
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/%22The%20Bark%20Side%22
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => %22Happy%20National%20Popcorn%20Day%22
                        [name] => Happy National Popcorn Day
                        [promoted_content] => 
                        [events] => 
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/%22Happy%20National%20Popcorn%20Day%22
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => %22Marianne%20Gingrich%22
                        [name] => Marianne Gingrich
                        [events] => 
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/%22Marianne%20Gingrich%22
                        [promoted_content] => 
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => %22Johnny%20Otis%22
                        [promoted_content] => 
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/%22Johnny%20Otis%22
                        [events] => 
                        [name] => Johnny Otis
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => %22iBooks%202%22
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/%22iBooks%202%22
                        [promoted_content] => 
                        [events] => 
                        [name] => iBooks 2
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => %22Heat%20vs%20Lakers%22
                        [name] => Heat vs Lakers
                        [promoted_content] => 
                        [events] => 
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/%22Heat%20vs%20Lakers%22
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [query] => %22Taylor%20Hall%22
                        [name] => Taylor Hall
                        [promoted_content] => 
                        [events] => 
                        [url] => http://twitter.com/search/%22Taylor%20Hall%22
                    )

            )

        [created_at] => 2012-01-19T18:09:12Z
        [locations] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => United States
                        [woeid] => 23424977
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

How would I echo just the two trending hashtags from this output?  I'm sure this is really simple, but I'm not a trained programmer (this is for a psychology research project) and I'm a bit lost.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($json_output[0]['trends'] as $trend) {

    if ($trend['name'][0] === '#') {

       echo $trend['name'];

    }

}
```

If you want 2 trends max:

```
$count = 0;

foreach($json_output[0]['trends'] as $trend) {


    if ($trend['name'][0] === '#') {

       echo $trend['name'];
       $count++;

       if ($count === 2) break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, I think I wasn't particularly clear.  I'm trying to create a loop that would go through whatever array is collected (after multiple calls) and check each ['name'] to see if it starts with a hashtag and then, if it does, echo it/save it to a variable.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You are officially my hero.  :D

Comment: Does this title come with a prize??

Comment: My undying gratitude and...COOKIES.  Well, at least one of the two.  ;)

Comment: Haha, awesome. Good luck with your project

Comment: How do I get tweet_volume along with Tweet , If its not null ... 
[name] => Mステ 
[url] => twitter.com/search?q=M%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86 [promoted_content] => [query] => M%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86 [tweet_volume] => 102516 Tweet volum is empty in some trends ...